# when should we use the read uncommited

Tags: transaction

I am reading the database isolation level, and I found the read uncommited isolation level. my question is: what the purpose of the read uncommited isolation level? when should we use the read uncommited level? all the document said the it is dangious to use the low level of isolation, why design the read uncommited isolation level?

Comment: "why design the read uncommited isolation level" -- same reason why some applications are OK with eventual consistency.

Comment: you mean some application are tolerance with this? @mustaccio

Comment: I think the point is that some queries do not need absolutely consistent data on read, and it's more important that they run without getting blocked by modification queries.